# How do I run a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Forget any form of server configuration (e.g. sites-enabled / Apache / nginx). Imagine all my files are publicly accessible in a web server.

I have these folders available:

```
/app/assets

/app/controllers

/app/helpers

/app/mailers

/app/models

/app/observers

/app/uploaders

/app/views

/public/
```

I don't have any more folders than this.

If I go to domain.com/public/htmlpage.html then I can see that HTML render fine. If I go to domain.com/public/ then I get a "Index file doesn't exists" message.

How do I run the Rails app? What file am I supposed to run in the web browser?

Comment: You can't forget about server configuration. Rails has to be started on the server not from the browser

Comment: I just want to test something locally in a browser. Can't you do that?

Comment: Yes. run 'rails s' and go to localhost:3000 in your browser. In your question you are describing a behavior. Try to tell us what you want to do and what you've tired. We are here to help you. Don't be discouraged by downvotes. Take a look at your question and edit it.

Comment: Did you create a rails application using `rails new applicationname` command? As that command should give you more than the folders that you listed. For the `rails s` to run, you need `config.ru` file in the application folder plus the `config` folder with all the application specific configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cd to your project root directory, which is directory one above you app directory and run command

```
bundle install
```

and later

```
rails s
```

this command will run your webrick server on port 3000, since you are running your application on localhost you can use this URL to check your application in browser

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

you can append name of any file that you have in your public directory to run as

```
http://localhost:3000/htmlpage.html
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very clear to understand, but I've done that and I get a "Protocol error - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails or s/vendor/rails" error after I use "rails s".

Comment: @user2143356 are you using RVM

Comment: Yes. I set up an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Vagrant/VirtualBox and nginx. I used RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @user2143356 run `bundle install` command first and then when it finishes execution run `rails s`

Comment: Thanks, but I get exactly the same, a "Protocol error - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails or s/vendor/rails" error

Comment: @user2143356 okay, so further investigating after running `rvm install` command, did you run `rvm use 1.9.2` command

Answer (score 1):

You just go to domain.com, no need for the public

Edit:

Ok to start it locally you can ssh in and run rails s.

Comment: There's nothing there that relates to my Ruby app. My file structure is as shown above. Do you mean domain.com/app/views/something ?

Comment: No I mean go to domain.com.  Rails will then serve whatever your application is routed to

Comment: That isn't working. I want to avoid server config as I have even more problems with that. Which file runs the app?

Comment: If you have no server configuration then obviously it's not going to run

Comment: So which file runs it? In Symfony2 on PHP the file might be /symfony/web/app.php - which one is it in Rails?

Comment: It'll run through a http server, you don't simply run an executable

Comment: Thanks. So where do I point the server config to? Surely the server config should be pointed to one file? Imagine nginx. Do I point the nginx config to the 'public' folder, the /app/ folder, a particular file, where?

Comment: This doc should contain any info you'd need.
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html

Comment: Locally you can run rails s when sshed in.  nginx wise point it to the public folder

Comment: Which folder do you run rails s in? /app/, /public/ ?

Comment: Thanks. I've done that but I get a "Protocol error - /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails or s/vendor/rails" error

Answer (score 0):

Rails apps are dynamic - they work with a db backend & lots of [middleware](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html)

---

You should read [how to get started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) (you'll benefit from reading `4.2` onwards):

> 4.2 Say "Hello"
>
> Rails To get Rails saying "Hello", you need to create at minimum a controller and a view.
>
> A controller's purpose is to receive specific requests for the
>   application. Routing decides which controller receives which requests.
>   Often, there is more than one route to each controller, and different
>   routes can be served by different actions. Each action's purpose is to
>   collect information to provide it to a view.
>
> A view's purpose is to display this information in a human readable
>   format. An important distinction to make is that it is the controller,
>   not the view, where information is collected. The view should just
>   display that information. By default, view templates are written in a
>   language called ERB (Embedded Ruby) which is converted by the request
>   cycle in Rails before being sent to the user.

---

You'll need this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "application#index"

#app/controller/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
end

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
Hello World
```

Then go to `http://localhost:3000/` after booting your web server with `rails s`